# maintain hover menu on mouseover in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hover

I have a table with some customer data. I am using jquery hover to show the `actions(Edit, Delete, View)` for the customer.

Below is the html:

```
<table id="hovertable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 1 Column 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Row 1 Column 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="iVal" value="1" />
            Row 1 Column 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 2 Column 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Row 2 Column 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="iVal" value="2" />
            Row 2 Column 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Row 3 Column 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Row 3 Column 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="iVal" value="3" />
            Row 3 Column 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<div id="hovermenu" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
    <a href="Home/Edit/" id="hoverlink">Edit</a>
</div>
```

And the script is here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        $("#hovertable tr").hover(
          function() {
              var pTop = $(this).offset().top;
              var pLeft = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() - "10";
              $('#hoverlink').attr("href", "/Home/Edit/" + $(this).find('input[name=iVal]').val());
              $("#hovermenu").css({
                  top: pTop,
                  left: pLeft
              }).show();
          },
          function() {
             $("#hovermenu").hide();
          });
    });
</script>
```

When i move the mouse on each row of the table, i can able to show the actions for the customer row. But when i move the mouse over the `actions(Edit, Delete, View)`, it hides the hover menu.

Whats the way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your javascript :

```
$("#hovermenu").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).show();
  },
  function(){}
);
```

It should keep your menu displayed while hovering it.

Comment: Your example demonstrates hover(in, out), so the menu will never be hidden. Out event should fire a hide function.

$("#hovermenu").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).show();
  },
  function(){
    $(this).hide();
  }
);

Comment: Not true, it already is hidden on the row's hover out. You don't want to hide the "edit" menu when you hover out it, only when you hover out the row it is related to.
I tried this code, it works.

Comment: I edited my answer, you don't need to do anything on hover out.